# yiiframework Action delete is not showing setflash

Tags: php, ajax, yii

```
    public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        try 
        {
            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();
            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
                if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
                    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));          
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            throw new CTestException('User in use, Delete Refrences.');
            //Yii::app ()->user->setFlash ( 'error', "User in use, Delete Refrences." );
        }


    }
    else
    {
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
    }
}
```

I want to catch the inner exception and show an alert. its setflash is not working plus if i'm throwing a custom exception it's alerting the stack of error 500 as well, the exception which im trying to handl.

Comment: your `setflash` line is commented out, so it won't be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to put the setFlash call before the throw as throws end the function in a similar manner to return statements.

Also, uncomment the statement.